# Difference between Drop Folder and Build Agent Working Directory in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration

I am setting up Team Foundation server for the first time and am attempting to set up automated builds for an ASP.NET MVC project. I have it all working but I don't really understand what is happening.

In my build definition it asks me to set a Drop Folder location.  When a build task is added to the queue, once it is successful it not only adds a build folder into the drop folder location, but it also adds a folder called Builds with build files in it based on the Build Agent's working directory.

Additionally, the drop folder builds contain all the debug files such as Web.Debug.config and .pdb files.

What is the purpose of both of these folders? Do I require both to be on my build server?  How do I use the builds for releases to production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drop folder holds the results of the build. It only holds debug files if you built the Debug configuration.

The Builds folder is where the build actually executes. The default directory is set to a location within this folder during the execution of the build. As a result, it contains the intermediate files, among other things - whatever the compilers and such produce, even as input to another tool.

A drop folder allows you to refer to the results of a build in several ways. You may choose to deploy the build results, or you might have another build reference the results of this build.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, while the build agent compiles the application it stores the output in the Builds folder.  Then once it is done, it copies the results of the build out to the drop folder to be used/referenced/etc?

Comment: So what is the reason for keeping the Builds folder around? Can I automatically remove that somehow once the build is complete?

Comment: Why bother? It will be reused. Also, in the case of CI builds, the Builds folder isn't cleared - it keeps around the files from the previous CI build, so that the build will only build what has changed.

Comment: Great, I understand it much better now, thanks for your help.  Now to work out how to build in Release configuration :S

Comment: Edit the build definition. In the "Process" tab, under "Items to build", select the configuration you want to build.

Comment: I had done that - it says Configurations to Build - Any CPI|Release - but it still includes the .pdb files with each .dll, plus it includes both Web.Release.config and Web.Debug.config.

Comment: You should really ask a separate question about those issues, and link to it here.